# VirtualBox vboxnet0 responds on pings to 192.168.56.100, which is not associated to any virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I configured a VirtualBox virtual machine via vagrant to have a private_network address at 192.168.56.100 and noticed that I can ping the address, but not ssh to it.

After some investigation I found out that even when I shut down the VM I still can ping the address 192.168.56.100, while no VirtualBox VM is running.

And even more strange, when I reconfigure my Vagrant file to use the address 192.168.56.101 and then reboot my host machine. Then initially after reboot vboxnet0 does not exist and I cannot ping any of the 192.168.56.* addresses. When I then start the virtual machine via vagrant up then vboxnet0 becomes available at 192.168.56.1 and the new VM becomes available at 192.168.56.101. But then I still can ping 192.168.56.100?? No VM exists that would use this address!

How can I debug this further? How can I find out what 192.168.56.100 is? vboxnet0 is not a brdige device, so I can't use tools like brctl.

Thanks!

P.S.: I am on "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS": Linux master 5.15.0-30-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 10:00:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I am using VirtualBox in version 6.1.32_Ubuntu r149290.

First here is the additonal information as requested before I `vagrant up`.

```
ip route sh
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-87529e8f38b0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-09115dd7adf5 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-95476c66ec3f proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-f259d334ba7f proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.63 metric 600 

ip addr show | grep 'inet '
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet 192.168.178.63/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-09115dd7adf5
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-87529e8f38b0
inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-95476c66ec3f
inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-f259d334ba7f

ping 192.168.56.100
PING 192.168.56.100 (192.168.56.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.56.100 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3080ms
```

And here the same after `vagrant up`:

```
ip route sh
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-87529e8f38b0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-09115dd7adf5 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-95476c66ec3f proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-f259d334ba7f proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.56.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.1 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.63 metric 600

ip addr show | grep 'inet '
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet 192.168.178.63/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-09115dd7adf5
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-87529e8f38b0
inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-95476c66ec3f
inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-f259d334ba7f
inet 192.168.56.1/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global vboxnet0
```

The VM that I start has the IP 192.168.56.101 and responds as it should:

```
ping 192.168.56.101
PING 192.168.56.101 (192.168.56.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.364 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.205 ms
```

But something is also responding on 192.168.56.100 now:

```
ping 192.168.56.100
PING 192.168.56.100 (192.168.56.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.078 ms
```

Comment: I find reasonable to add at least the results for `ip route sh` and `ip addr show | grep 'inet '` while no VM are instanciated.

Comment: The address may be the one used by the DHCP server implemented by virtual box. You can check this in the virtual box config (in linux using `vboxmanage` command line, or from the GUI).

Comment: @Brahim Gaabab: you are right! I checked via the File -> Host Network Manager GUI, then switched to the DHCP tab and there it says "Server Address: 192.168.56.100". I would have never guessed that. I would have guessed that the "base address" 192.168.56.1 would serve as DHCP server, too. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! I rolled back your recent edit referring to comment as the answer. If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Comments are for temporary discussions around clarifications etc., and can not be considered actual answers (as they may disappear at any time). Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @BrahimGaabab If you have a solution, please consider writing it as a proper answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was acutally provided by @BrahimGaabab:
I checked via the File -> Host Network Manager GUI, then switched to the DHCP tab and there it says "Server Address: 192.168.56.100".

I would have never guessed that. I would have guessed that the "base address" 192.168.56.1 would serve as DHCP server, too.